# SQLServer 2016 continually increasing stolen memory

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, memory, numa

We are experiencing a slow growth of Stolen Memory on our database servers over the space of several days. It appears to plateau around 130-140GB, at which point we start having larger problems such as out-of-memory errors, multi-second freezes & AG failovers. Problems start to manifest about a week after a reboot. I have started recording history of stolen memory, which is shown below:

[image: Stolen memory over time]

Looking at `sys.dm_os_memory_clerks`, it appears as if the bulk of this is coming from non-page memory recorded against the buffer pool on NUMA node 0:

[image: Buffer pool memory clerks]

Tracking the total `pages_kb` for the buffer pool over time shows the decline in number of pages as `virtual_memory_committed_kb` grows. (On April 13th, the server was rebooted for windows updates. The buffer pool fills to 400GB in around an hour)

[image: Buffer pool pages]

Has anyone seen this behaviour before?

We are running SQLServer 2016 CU12 13.0.5698.0 The server is a 64-core AWS EC2 i3.16xlarge instance. We have a number of other clusters of the same size that are all showing this issue. We also have a few clusters on 32-core i3.8xlarge instances that also show the growth in stolen memory, but they don't end up stalling / throwing out-of-memory errors. The only difference (other than scale) is that the 64-core servers have 2 NUMA nodes.

[image: Server config]

**Update:**
MS indicated that the bugfix in KB4536005 is not being back-ported to SQL2016.

Comment: No columnstore workloads.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i have a suspicion.  First - are you able to open support tickets with Microsoft?

Easiest way to check my suspicion is capture [\SQLServer:Memory Node(*)\Stolen Node Memory (KB)] for both NUMA nodes, and compare the sum to [\SQLServer:Memory Manager\Stolen Server Memory (KB)].  If my suspicion is correct, when trouble is brewing the discrepancy between the two - which seem like they should always agree - will be quite high.  The other tell-tale characteristic: up to N-1 SQLOS NUMA nodes may have show this relationship (where N is the count of NUMA nodes)
[database node memory] + [stolen node memory] + [free node memory] > [total node memory]

i describe the problem somewhat in these blog posts.

https://sql-sasquatch.blogspot.com/2018/07/sql-server-2016-memory-accounting.html
https://sql-sasquatch.blogspot.com/2018/10/sql-server-2016-memory-accounting-part.html

The basic accounting problem is that sometimes buffer pool growth occurs in a way that buffer descriptor blocks get allocated from SQLOS node A but the pages referenced in the bdbs actually come from SQLOS node B.  The result of this condition is that a portion of physical memory controlled by SQLOS gets double-counted: the same memory is accounted on node A (where the bdbs live) as [Database Node Memory] *AND* accounted on SQLOS node B as [Stolen Node Memory].  That situation is confusing and inefficient... but its not the full bloom of the problem yet.

The problem fully blooms when so much Node B [stolen node memory] is also Node A [database node memory] that Node B [database node memory] drops to ~2% of Node B [target node memory].  When that happens, the rate of [\SQLServer:Buffer Manager\Free list stalls/sec] skyrockets - we saw 2000/sec when this happened to us.  SQL Server is *trying* to correct the issue (too little [database node memory]) on Node B by trimming various types of cache on Node B.  But it can't!! Because the [stolen node memory] isn't in any of the various expected cache types.

Temporary resolution: when [total node memory] approaches [target node memory] but [database node memory] approaches 2% of [target node memory], execute DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS.

kb4536005 resolves this issue in SQL Server 2017 CU20 and SQL Server 2019 CU2.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4536005/improvement-fix-incorrect-memory-page-accounting-that-causes-out-of-me

There is a similar *sounding* fix in SQL Server 2016 SP2 CU5, kb4470916.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4470916/fix-out-of-memory-error-occurs-when-database-node-memory-kb-drops-belo

However, I don't believe kb4470916 resolves the issue with double-accounting.  So while it may improve SQL Server response to a single SQLOS node having [database node memory] at the ~2% threshold, i think it leaves open the possibility of poking the bear due to this double-counting.  And that may be the situation you are in.

However, if the sum of [stolen node memory] across the two nodes always aligns with [stolen server memory] in the instance, you can forget all about this as if it were a bad dream. :-)

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if we were experiencing the issue fixed in kb4470916 - until a few weeks ago we were still on SQL2016 SP2 CU4, and that KB was included in CU5

Comment: I've added some monitoring on those metrics you've mentioned... we're seeing quite an inbalance in database / target memory between the 2 NUMA nodes...

Comment: is SQL Server engine proper the only big memory consumer on the VM? Got SSAS or SSIS cohabiting? Looking for imbalance in [\NUMA Node Memory(*)\Free & Zero Page List MBytes] between nodes should give a hint toward other suspects i have in mind.

Comment: SQLServer should be the only large memory user, however there are things like database backups being uploaded to S3. We've kept around 32GB/488GB of RAM for OS etc, which we've assumed will be enough.

Comment: I'm not sure if the original problem we were getting was related to your answer, however we had an unscheduled failover last night that *did* show a 50GB difference between node stolen and total stolen.